# How to access the file in the main bundle of project with cocoapod installed

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I was trying to follow AppCoda tutorial about the Lottie framework but I couldn't access the file in bundle. It shows this image:
[File can't be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMAvB.png).  And also if I check the content, it's not there [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5cUp.png)

But the file is copied in the directory if we check in Finder.
I notice that projects without cocoapod work fine, I can access the resources.

I have tried to create a new project, then install the framework using cocoapod several times assuming maybe there was installation error or whatnot but I still don't know how to access the file.
I am using Xcode9beta6.

So I think this is my lack of knowledge of how to access the resources in cocoapod installed project. I have searched for the solution but couldn't find the same one. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: check in your build phases if there is the resource, I have several projects working with cocoapods and loading jsons from files without problem

Comment: @ReinierMelian you are right. there are only three files in the "Copy bundle Resources" section, after I added my files there the problem is gone. But this leads me to another question. Do you have to add your resources manually there if you install a pod in your project, or it's just a bug in Xcode 9? This is is my first time using Cocoapod, and there is no documentation telling me to do so. Btw, thank you for the clarification!